# How to download and install specific version of sun-java6-jdk on ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, apt

I am using Ubuntu version 12.04 (via VM)

I downloaded and installed java:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

The version is:

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.4) (6b24-1.11.4-1ubuntu0.12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

But I need the version:

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_20"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.13) (6b20-1.9.13-0ubuntu1~10.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)
```

How can I download and install sun-java6-jdk version 1.6.0_20?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For installing the particular version of `sun java` run:

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk=1.6.0_20
```

Then to choose the default java installation run the following and choose the correct installation:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Comment: I get this: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '1.6.0_20' for 'sun-java6-jdk' was not found

Comment: It appears the sun java packages are not present in the ubuntu repos anymore. Follow the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java) to get and install them from alternative locations.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Source: [Ubuntu Community Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java).

Comment: I get this:
There is only one alternative in link group java: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
Nothing to configure.